# Gracefully stopping a Java process in a pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I've read the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/production-pods.html#lifecycle-hooks-and-termination-notice) on graceful termination of a pod in Kubernetes but I'm not quite sure how to map my specific use case of shutting down a Java process gracefully.

What I want to do is to run the following bash command as a part of the termination process:

```
$ kill -SIGTERM `pidof java`
```

I've tried this:

```
...    
lifecycle:
    preStop:
      exec:                
        command: ["kill", "-SIGTERM", "`pidof java`"]
...
```

But nothing happens but the Java shutdown hook doesn't seem to kick-in when I stop the pod (`kubectl stop pod pod-xxx`). I suspect that the `pidof java` part of the `kill` command doesn't work (but I'm not sure). How would I do this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started a bash shell inside the container and executed my command instead and that turned out to work:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "PID=`pidof java` && kill -SIGTERM $PID && while ps -p $PID > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done;"]
```

Without `/bin/bash` I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why your script is not doing anything. Maybe the command is not in the container, maybe you should try with full path (/bin/kill)?

But, kubernetes will send SIGTERM to the application when it does stop, so your script doesn't improve anything. It will wait after that for terminationGracePeriodSeconds and it will do a force kill.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/user-guide/production-pods.md#lifecycle-hooks-and-termination-notice

Comment: I found this link useful, it describes why some people launching a JVM may not be receiving the SIGTERM they expect: http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html

Answer (score 0):

It works in my Kubernetes environment , 8 - PID of my java process:

```
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            # SIGTERM triggers a gracefully terminate
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kill 8",]
```